# How to skip elements in a jsp loop?

Tags: java

```
<loop list="<%=components%>">              
      <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
      <table class="standard">
      <tr>
        <loop list="<%=components%>" limit="4">                  
          <td valign="top">
            <pass name="component" value="<%=listobj%>" />
            <include page="component" arg1="<%=componentID%>"  />
          </td>                  
        </mmp:loop>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
      </tr>      
      <% java.util.Collections.rotate(components,Integer.parseInt(4)); %>
    </loop>
```

I want to create a new row after every four elements of the list has been printed. So i used the loop twice. But The outer loop only skips one element every loop, while the inner loop prints 4 elements. so after the inner loop finishes, i want the outer loop to advance 4 times . I tried using rotate, but it just rearranges the collection. It does not advance the index by four places.

Comment: Why's the table inside the first loop? are you printing multiple tables or rows?

Comment: I have a table inside the row of a table. so the first tr you see is within a table which i havent shown here. I have created another table within the row so the UI is structured well.I am printing multiples rows, but there is a table inside each row.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(4)` shouldn't compile.

Comment: It wont compile, i actually have an integer there

Comment: *variable....i just used 4 everywhere to make it simple